# ¿Cómo habilitar el teclado dentro de un WebView?

Tags: java, android, webview

tengo un problema al querer mostrar una página en un `WebView`, lo que pasa es que cuando selecciono un campo de texto el teclado no aparece como se muestra en la imagen, al principio pensé que era la página así que probé con una diferente pero el resultado fue el mismo.
[image: Imagen del formulario, esta seleccionado el campo texto]
Lo que quiero sabes es si existe alguna instrucción o método para que me muestre el teclado de antemano gracias.
Anexo el código en el que lo creo y el Xml.

```
//Lo mando a traer en una vista inflada.
   AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            vistaInfladaMapa = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.mapa_transporte,null);
            alert.setView(vistaInfladaMapa);
            mapa = vistaInfladaMapa.findViewById(R.id.webview);
            mapa.loadUrl("https://vuelo-duracion.com/");

            WebSettings webSettings = mapa.getSettings ();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled ( true );
            AlertDialog aler = alert.create();
            aler.show();
```

Y el Xml.

```
  <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="753dp" />
```

Les agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Hola @Alfredo, ¿Estas usando un emulador?

Comment: Hola @Serna si utilizo un emulador, y la par una tablet Samsung Tab A 6.

Comment: @Alfredo tienes alguna configuración en tu AndroidManifest.xml para esta Activity? se supone que debería mostrase

Comment: @Jorgesys no tengo ninguna configuración  <activity android:name=".activities.Compras" />, es todo lo que tiene.